# Maximize number of zigzag sequence in an array

Tags: algorithm, permutation

I want to maximize number of zigzag sequence in an array(without reordering).

I've a main array of random sequence of integers.I want a  sub-array of index of main array that has zigzag pattern.

A sequence of integers is called zigzag sequence if each of its elements is either strictly less or strictly greater than its neighbors(and two adjacent of neighbors).

**Example** : The sequence 4 2 3 1 5 2 forms a zigzag, but 7 3 5 5 2 and 3 8 6 4 5 
 and 4 2 3 1 5 3 don't.

For a given array of integers we need to find (contiguous) sub-array of indexes that forms a zigzag sequence.

Can this be done in O(N) ?

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you please add solution(s) that you have tried so far? That can help the community to understand where you are stuck.

Comment: Yes, it's easy. If an element breaks the check, it breaks for the subarray anyway. So, we move in from the next element. Now, have start and end indexes and keep storing values accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this would seem to be solvable in O(n) time. I'll describe the algorithm as a dynamic program.

### Setup

Let the array containing potential zig-zags be called `Z`.

Let `U` be an array such that `len(U) == len(Z)`, and `U[i]` is an integer representing the largest contiguous left-to-right subsequence starting at `i` that is a zig-zag such that `Z[i] < Z[i+1]` (it zigs up).

Let `D` be similar to `U`, except that `D[i]` is an integer representing the largest contiguous left-to-right subsequence starting at `i` that is a zig-zag such that `Z[i] > Z[i+1]` (it zags down).

### Subproblem

The subproblem is to find both `U[i]` and `D[i]` at each `i`. This can be done as follows:

```
U[i] = {
    1 + D[i+1]   if i < i+1
    0            otherwise
}

L[i] = {
    1 + U[i+1]   if i > i+1
    0            otherwise
}
```

The top version says that if we're looking for the largest sequence beginning with an up-zig, we see if the next element is larger (goes up), and then add a single zig to the size of the next down-zag sequence. The next one is the reverse.

### Base Cases

If `i == len(Z)` (it is the last element), `U[i] = L[i] = 0`. The last element cannot have a left-to-right sequence after it because there is nothing after it.

### Solution

To get the solution, first we find `max(U[i])` and `max(L[i])` for every `i`. Then get the maximum of those two values, store `i`, and store the length of this largest zig-zag (in a variable called `length`). The sequence begins at index `i` and ends at index `i + length`.

### Runtime

There are n indexes, so there are 2n subproblems between `U` and `L`. Each subproblem takes O(1) time to solve, given that solutions to previously solved subproblems are memoized. Finally, iterating through `U` and `L` to get the final answer takes O(2n) time.

We thus have O(2n) + O(2n) time, or **O(n)**.

This may be an overly complex solution, but it demonstrates that it can be done in O(n).